# save angular project on visual studio code without recompiling

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, save

Is there any way to save files in vscode without auto recompiling the angular project?
It's totally anoying, when you have to save 5 files and angular is compiling at least 3 times.

Comment: Why not just use the save all shortcut, if your problem is having to compile multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Angular dev server (`ng serve`) is running in some terminal on your computer, if you want to save files without having Angular recompile you'll need to stop the dev server to do so. That includes VS-Code's integrated terminal. This is because it's the `ng serve` process which is watching your files for changes, not VS-Code, so this will be true no matter which editor you use.

Another solution might be to use `ng serve --watch false`. This will run the dev server, but the server will not update when you save a file. If you want to update the runtime code, you'll need to stop the process with something like `CTRL+C` and run the command again to recompile your Angular code.